# Transaction rollback in Spring MVC controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, transactions, rollback

I have a Spring MVC controller annotated with `@Transaction`, and under certain inputs I need to rollback the transaction.

As I understand, the proper way to trigger a rollback is to throw an exception from the controller.

But if I throw an exception from the controller, I won't get a chance to return a `ModelAndView` object from the controller.

How can I trigger a rollback in the controller, while still providing a `ModelAndView` to be rendered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exceptions are the appropriate route to follow. Spring can [map exceptions to views](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-exceptionhandlers) as well. This is probably what you want to do.

Comment: I was afraid this was the answer.  Since I want my ModelAndView construction logic to live in the controller, I think I need to define a custom exception class that can store the ModelAndView, and a custom `HandlerExceptionResolver` to render it.  Seems like something that belongs in Spring itself.

Comment: Turns out there is something like that in Spring itself: [ModelAndViewDefiningException](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/ModelAndViewDefiningException.html)

Answer (score 2):

First, I don't think that using `@Transaction` on controller methods is a good thing.  It's better to keep transactional logic in a 'service tier' and use the `@Transaction` annotation there.

But if you still want to use `@Transaction` on the controller, take a look at `org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Sometimes controllers need to make multiple calls atomically—for instance, `User user = userService.getByUsername(...)`; `user.updateEmailAddr(...)`; `user.updateTelephone(...)`; `user.subscribeToMailingList(...)`. It seems silly to have to make a service method like `UserService.updateEmailAddrAndTelephoneAndSubscribeToMailingListByUsername` just so the controller doesn't have to be transactional.

Comment: I don't think it's silly at all.  If you have to write the code anyway why not encapsulate it in the service instead of in the controller?  Another benefit is then you can easily test it in your service test instead of worrying about the controller.